# Google Analytics User Tracking

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

is it possible to differentiate with Google Analytics between logged in and logged out users? Can I even track the data of each unique user by sending the User ID somehow via JS? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect logged  in user on a `specific url` if a specific google analytics id than a logged out one:

```
<?php
    if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo '
    your google analytics code here for logged in users   
        '
        ;
        } else {
           echo '
    your google analytics code here for public users 
        '
        ;
    }
```

FOR EXAMPLE, in the google analytics documentation:

```
if (isset($userId)) {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': '%s' });";
  echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
} else {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');";
  echo sprintf($gacode);
}
```

You can find more information here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id